# After closing stdout: Java silently swallows everything written to stdout

Tags: java, stdout

Have a look at this example:

```
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hi there!");
    System.out.close();
    System.out.println("I'm silently swallowed :(");
    System.out.flush(); // even flushing and closing again
    System.out.close(); // doesn't throw an Exception
    try {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
      fos.flush(); // same goes for this more direct approach
      fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
  }
}
```

Why doesn't the JVM tell me somehow, that writing to stdout failed? I would expect to get an Exception *somewhere*.

How else could I detect such a situation?

Comment: You can check with `checkError()`. There is a boolean `trouble` modifier in case of exceptions (having try catch everywhere seams to be a bad idea ;) ). This is resetable with `clearError()`

Comment: @DimaSan, I don't think it is a duplicate, one asked why we should close stream exception System's stream, here the question is why nothing bad happen when we use a closed stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Official specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) says it all.

> Unlike other output streams, a `PrintStream` never throws an `IOException`; instead, exceptional situations merely set an internal flag that can be tested via the `checkError` method.

If your question is "why did they decide to do it this way", then all we can do is make educated guesses, but opinions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: "why did they decide to do it this way"
That was not my question, but it is now :)
I find this really odd... but thanks for the answer!

Comment: Imagine having to put each and every `println` statement inside a try-catch. You might argue they could have just invented another unchecked IOException for this, but in the days of Java 1.0 this wasn't on the radar.